# Errors with resizing property sheet

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I'm trying to make a re-sizable property sheet using the example http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300606. However I get several errors in my code which I don't know how to overcome.
I created the property sheet using a class wizard on my Dialog.
I only need the re-size function mentioned in the article. Any help will be appreciated.

.cpp class

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "Geometry.h"
    #include "GeoSheet.h"


    // CGeoSheet

    IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CGeoSheet, CPropertySheet)


    CGeoSheet::CGeoSheet(UINT nIDCaption, CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT iSelectPage)
    :CPropertySheet(nIDCaption, pParentWnd, iSelectPage)
    {

    }

    CGeoSheet::CGeoSheet(LPCTSTR pszCaption, CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT iSelectPage)
    :CPropertySheet(pszCaption, pParentWnd, iSelectPage)
    {

    }

    CGeoSheet::~CGeoSheet()
    {
    }


    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CGeoSheet, CPropertySheet)
        ON_COMMAND(IDOK, OnOK)
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()



    // CGeoSheet message handlers

    void CGeoSheet::OnOK()  
    {
        CPropertySheet::OnClose();
    }

    // Overriding DoModal() allows us to hook our callback into
    //    the prop sheet creation
    int CGeoSheet::DoModal() 
    {
        // Hook into property sheet creation code
        AFX_OLDPROPSHEETHEADER* psh = GetPropSheetHeader();
        psh->dwFlags |= PSH_USECALLBACK;
        psh->pfnCallback = XmnPropSheetCallback;
        return CPropertySheet::DoModal();
    }


    // This function must be a STATIC member function. 
    //Callback to allow us set the default window styles 
    //    for the property sheet
    int CGeoSheet ::XmnPropSheetCallback(HWND hWnd, UINT message, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        extern int CALLBACK AfxPropSheetCallback(HWND, UINT message, LPARAM lParam);
        // XMN: Call MFC's callback
        int nRes = AfxPropSheetCallback(hWnd, message, lParam);

        switch (message)
        {
        case PSCB_PRECREATE:
            // Set our own window styles
            ((LPDLGTEMPLATE)lParam)->style |= (DS_3DLOOK | DS_SETFONT
                | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_SYSMENU | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION);
            break;
        }
        return nRes;
    }
```

.h file

```
#pragma once



// CGeoSheet

class CGeoSheet : public CPropertySheet
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CGeoSheet)

public:

    CGeoSheet(UINT nIDCaption, CWnd* pParentWnd = NULL, UINT iSelectPage = 0);
    CGeoSheet(LPCTSTR pszCaption, CWnd* pParentWnd = NULL, UINT iSelectPage = 0);
    virtual ~CGeoSheet();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    //{{AFX_MSG(CMyPropertySheet)
        // NOTE - the ClassWizard will add and remove member functions here.
    afx_msg void OnOK();
    int CGeoSheet::DoModal();
    int CGeoSheet ::XmnPropSheetCallback(HWND hWnd, UINT message, LPARAM lParam);
    //}}AFX_MSG

};
```

I keep getting these errors.

```
geosheet.cpp(49) : error C2065: 'AFX_OLDPROPSHEETHEADER' : undeclared identifier
geosheet.cpp(49) : error C2065: 'psh' : undeclared identifier
geosheet.cpp(49) : error C3861: 'GetPropSheetHeader': identifier not found
geosheet.cpp(50) : error C2065: 'psh' : undeclared identifier
geosheet.cpp(50) : error C2227: left of '->dwFlags' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
        type is ''unknown-type''
geosheet.cpp(51) : error C2065: 'psh' : undeclared identifier
geosheet.cpp(51) : error C2227: left of '->pfnCallback' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
        type is ''unknown-type''
```

**Edit**
I modified the DoModal function according to http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/VC/microsoft.public.vc.mfc/2005-09/msg00585.html; and now I get this single error.

Code:

```
int CGeoSheet::DoModal() 
{
    // Hook into property sheet creation code
    m_psh.dwFlags |= PSH_USECALLBACK;
    m_psh.pfnCallback = XmnPropSheetCallback;// <--Error
    return CPropertySheet::DoModal(); 
}
```

Error:

```
geosheet.cpp(50) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int (__cdecl *)(HWND,UINT,LPARAM)' to 'PFNPROPSHEETCALLBACK'
    This conversion requires a reinterpret_cast, a C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Comment: The missing 'AFX_OLDPROPSHEETHEADER' and GetPropSheetHeader definitions mean you are missing some include. Look in the Microsoft-example which one you are missing.

Comment: The function CGeoSheet ::XmnPropSheetCallback must not have a blank between CGeoSheet and the ::.<br>Also, it must be static.

Comment: I corrected the space, but the errors remain. Btw see edit.

Comment: `int (__cdecl *)(HWND,UINT,LPARAM)` is the signature of your `XmnPropSheetCallback` method: returning int, _cdecl call style and accepting HWND, UINT and LPARAM. The compiler says that is not the same as the type it needs, which is `typedef`ed as `PFNPROPSHEETCALLBACK`. Probably you need to have `XmnPropSheetCallback` be declared as `static int CALLBACK CGeoSheet::XmnPropSheetCallback(HWND hWnd, UINT message, LPARAM lParam);`

Answer (score 4):

You used CWndResizer class and you can resize your propertysheet.

in header file include cwndresizer class and make object of this class.
CWndResizer resizer;

in cpp file you can resize all control in propertysheet.

BOOL ClassName::OnInitDialog()
{

```
CPropertySheet::OnInitDialog();
    BOOL ok = FALSE;
ok = resizer.Hook(this);
ASSERT(ok);
```

// IDC_POLYGONS_LIST control id which you want to resize

```
ok = resizer.SetAnchor(IDC_POLYGONS_LIST,ANCHOR_LEFT|ANCHOR_TOP|ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
ASSERT(ok);
   bOk = resizer.SetParent("CS",IDC_STATIC_GROUPBOX2);
ASSERT(bOk);
```

}

for more detail you follow this link.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125068/MFC-C-Helper-Class-for-Window-Resizing

Answer (score 0):

The error is because in the .h you forgot to set your callback to static

```
int CGeoSheet ::XmnPropSheetCallback(HWND hWnd, UINT message, LPARAM lParam);
```

should be

```
static int CGeoSheet::XmnPropSheetCallback(HWND hWnd, UINT message, LPARAM lParam);
```